# How can i open a window popup in Servlet and then Redirect a Page

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, popup

I want to open a popup window on calling a servlet and then want to redirect servlet to some `.jsp` page.

This is what i've done:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        out.println("window.open(\"pageA.jsp\")");
        out.println("</script>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        response.sendRedirect("pageB.jsp");
    }
```

This code will only popup window when the `response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");` is not present or commented. Currently with this code, it is not popping a window and directly redirecting this page to `error.jsp`

How can i do both of the above things at the same time?

Comment: You cannot use sendRedirect(), what that is used for is the client asked for **A** but the server says you really want **B**. What you are doing is returning **A** but in such a way that it loads **B** for that you need to use javascript or a meta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting a page using `sendRedirect`, Use

`window.location.href = 'pageB.jsp'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript do the trick. For example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    out.println("var popwin = window.open(\"pageA.jsp\")");
    out.println("setTimeout(function(){ popwin.close(); window.location.href='pageB.jsp';},5000)");
    out.println("</script>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can call a jsp page instead of servlet and canuse a jQuery plugin thickbox

http://thickbox.net/