# How to open another JSP page in popup window in Java

Tags: java, jsp

I want to open a new JSP page as a popup window. After the submit button is clicked, the user can provide data without leaving the main page. For now, it simply redirects to another page, which makes the page a bit less user friendly.

I am using this code to redirect to the other page:

```
response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/APP/add.jsp");
```

And it works correctly, but it is not satisfying for me.

Comment: in your form tag add `target="_blank"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i open a window popup in Servlet and then Redirect a Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146883/how-can-i-open-a-window-popup-in-servlet-and-then-redirect-a-page)

Comment: well, it was trivial :) 

Thank You Ilya, have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code. Here **mypopup** is a java script function which will show the popup window. It takes a parameter url. You can use this function on your submit button click.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    function mypopup(url) {
                        width = window.screen.width;
                        height = window.screen.height;
                        mywindow = window.open(url, "Title",
                            "location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,menubar=0,toolbar=no,width="
                                        + width + ",height=" + height);
                        mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
                        mywindow.focus();
                    }
    </script>

<input type="submit"
                onclick='mypopup("http://localhost:8080/APP/add.jsp");return false;' value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: The effect would be way more better, but i'm not familiar with javascript yet, so I wanted to avoid using it  and make it pure java/html+css for now.